# How to use URL Shortener API Client Library for Java in android studio?

Tags: android, google-api, google-oauth, google-url-shortener, google-plus-signin

I am using Google+ Sign-In in my Android app and i want to send auth token to my web server.I follow the link
[https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/backend-auth][1] 
and uses the following code to generate idToken.

```
private class GetIdTokenTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String accountName = Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient);
        Account account = new Account(accountName, GoogleAuthUtil.GOOGLE_ACCOUNT_TYPE);
        String scopes = "audience:server:client_id:" + Constants.SERVER_CLIENT_ID; // Not the app's client ID.
        String idToken = "";
        try {
            idToken = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(getApplicationContext(), account, scopes);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error retrieving ID token.", e);
        } catch (GoogleAuthException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error retrieving ID token.", e);
        }
        return idToken;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        authToken=result;
        Log.i(TAG, "ID token: " + result);

    }

}
```

and  i get an id  token like this:

> eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IxxxxxNThkODVjODU3hiMjI3MjBhM2E1NWxxxxzM0NDcifQ.eyJpc3MiOiJhY2NvdW50cy5nb29nbGUuY29tIiwic3ViIjoiMTEyMzA2OTkwMjA1NDYyMjkzMDExIiwiYXpwIjoiNDU5NTM4MTI1OTIzLXUzNTEzNGZ0aTZyOWJnNGM4MDFjZW82MzVhNWVoNTZzLmFwcHMuZ29vZ2xldXNlcmNvbnRlbnQuY29tIiwiZW1haWwiOiJsZWppbmtyQGdtYWlsLmNvbSIsImVtYWlsX3ZlcmlmaWVkIjp0cnVlLCJhdWQiOiI0NTk1MzgxMjU5MjMtNDZlN3Q3YzNhbmQ3M2VqcThyZWZvZTFzYTIzdm9wOHEuYXBwcy5nb29nbGV1c2VyY29udGVudC5jb20iLCJpYXQiOjE0MzI2MzI5ODUsImV4cCI6MTQzMjYzNjU4NX0.vCT8lanz5Pa2_m_AQ4tZHaME_y_ffa5zqA5_O3u7ZhuOQTmK8xXUh7M-Q_R67KosGPX-ikr_7Tz57OiXNIyKtNBOFKssssxxE0v7wEJvFhVgLSpbuD

is this the real format of idToken?

but my back end server auth token need a format like this(Some other people doing back end)

```
ya29.QwGqNA9LsssggddjKZxxRD74HT_viU0wHxoDieWbsIJG3R0xvW3bDij4jzxxxxxP6wPSi7w1bysA
```

and back end coders suggest me to use something like
urlshortener and
userinfo.email
to get that kind of token.How can i get this type of token?
I am using GoogleApiClient for connecting with google plus and drive api in following code:

```
if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addApi(Drive.API)
                    .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
                    .addApi(Plus.API)
                    .addScope(new Scope("profile"))
                    .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_APPFOLDER) // required for App Folder sample
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                    .build();
        }

        findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mGoogleApiClient.connect();

            }
        });
```

how to get the auth token in the shortened format i described above?